# How to get the index value from a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript only!
I'm trying to get the index after clicked on one element from a dropdown menu.
I'm already getting the text value but not the index. How can I solve this?

1)This is how I get the text value after clicking on a month:

```
const monthText = document.querySelector(".month-text");
const months = document.querySelectorAll(".month-value");
const monthsEl = Array.from(months);

months.forEach((el) =\> {
el.onclick = function () {
const monthSelected = (monthText.textContent = this.innerHTML);
console.log(monthSelected);
};
});
```

2)I'm getting the index but with hard code ("May"):

```
const monthsArr = monthsEl.map((el) => el.textContent);
console.log(monthsArr);
const index = monthsArr.indexOf("May");
console.log(index);
```

[image: As you can see, I'm getting the string object, the selected month after clicked and the hard-coded index]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - please do not post images of code/console output. Paste the text here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of foreach, if you want to play with the index of the returned array, use map:

```
months.map((el, index) => {
    el.onclick = function () {
    const indexValue = index;
    const monthSelected = (monthText.textContent = this.innerHTML);
    console.log('Month ' + monthSelected + 'is at ' + index + 1 + 'position');
};
```

```js
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April']

months.map((el, index) => {
const indexValue = index;
    const monthSelected = el
    console.log('Month ' + monthSelected + ' is at ' + Number(index) + ' position')
        return index
    
})
```

Comment: For some reason, It didn't work with map, but with forEach(el, index) yes.

Answer (score 1):

the second argument of map is the index of the current element being processed in the array., maybe you can check that. Same as for each.

map((element, index) => { /* … */ })

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

In your map function, pass second argument and name it index, it will return the position of the object in the array.

```
const monthsArr = monthsEl.map((el, index) => el.textContent = el.index);
```

[Learn more about Index in mapping](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/index-inside-map-function/#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20map()%20method,t%20change%20the%20original%20array.)